# Opencv 3.1.0 with python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, torch, opencv3.1

It is possible to install **opencv 3.1.0** (it is only one version suitable for torch) with **python 3.7**? 
If it is possible, how can I do this? 
I'm on the very start of my developer path, so sorry for the silly question.